# How to create pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to this, but I have come a long way.

I ran `npm install react-router-dom` in the terminal and add the pages I want in the src/components/pages.

My main page is HomePage.jsx but that page is blank, I can´t see anything.
and in the inspect I can see:

> Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a  component

I can´t find what the problem is, I miss something.

I follow this tutorial: https://isotropic.co/react-multiple-pages/

My structure is :

```
  ├── node_modules
  ├── public
  ├── src
  │    ├── components
  │    │     └── HomePage
  │    │            ├── Destinations
  │    │            │      ├── Destinations.jsx
  │    │            │      └── Destinations.module.css
  │    │            ├── NavBar
  │    │            │      ├── NavBar.jsx
  │    │            │      └── NavBar.module.css
  │    │            ├── pages
  │    │            │      ├── about.jsx
  │    │            │      └── help.jsx
  │    │            ├── Search
  │    │            │      ├── Search.jsx
  │    │            │      └── Search.module
  │    │            ├── YoutubeAd
  │    │            ├── Footer.jsx
  │    │            ├── Footer.module.css
  │    │            └── HomePage.jsx
  │    │ 
  │    ├── App.css
  │    ├── App.js
  │    ├── index.js   
  │    └── index.css
```

my app.js i have this code:

```
    import './App.css'; 
import {HomePage} from './components/HomePage/HomePage.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import About from "./components/HomePage/pages/about";
import Help from "./components/HomePage/pages/help";
import Contact from "./components/HomePage/pages/contact";
import Login from "./components/HomePage/pages/login";
import SignUp from "./components/HomePage/pages/signup";
import PrivateCharter from "./components/HomePage/pages/privatecharter";
import FullDayFishing from "./components/HomePage/pages/fulldayfishing";
import HalfDayFishing from "./components/HomePage/pages/halfdayfishing";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}>
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="help" element={<Help />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="privatecharter" element={<PrivateCharter />} />
      <Route path="fulldayfishing" element={<FullDayFishing />} />
      <Route path="halfdayfishing" element={<HalfDayFishing />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

On my homepage.jsx

```
export const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Search />
            <Favorites />
            {/*<Destinations/>*/}
            <YoutubeAd />
            {/*<TopAttractions />*/}
            {/*<TopDestinations />*/}
            {/*<TopCountries />*/}
            {/*<AttractionCategories/>*/}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and in NavBar.jsx is the menu:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './NavBar.module.css'
import { MdLanguage } from 'react-icons/md';
import { HiOutlineUserGroup } from 'react-icons/hi';
import { BiHelpCircle } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { FiShoppingCart } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { FiMail } from 'react-icons/fi';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import { IoIosArrowDown } from 'react-icons/io';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

// The forwardRef is important!!
// Dropdown needs access to the DOM node in order to position the Menu
const CustomToggle = React.forwardRef(({ children, onClick }, ref) => (
  <a className="nav-link" href=""
    ref={ref}
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick(e);
    }}
  > {children} <IoIosArrowDown />
  </a>
));

// forwardRef again here!
// Dropdown needs access to the DOM of the Menu to measure it
const CustomMenu = React.forwardRef(
  ({ children, style, className, 'aria-labelledby': labeledBy }, ref) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    return (
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={style}
        className={className}
        aria-labelledby={labeledBy}
      >
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
          {React.Children.toArray(children).filter(
            (child) =>
              !value || child.props.children.toLowerCase().startsWith(value),
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  },
);

export const NavBar = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.navbar}>
                <div className={styles.navLogo}>
                <a className="nav-link" href="/"><img src="logo_286.png"  /></a>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.navLinks}>
                    <div><MdLanguage /> {t('language')}</div>
                    <div><a className="nav-link" href="/about">{t('about_us')}</a></div>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Sign up for xxxxxx</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Create an account to add things to your wishlist and access your bookings from any device.
         
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>

                        <Dropdown>
                            <Dropdown.Toggle as={CustomToggle} id="dropdown-custom-components">{t('fishing_trips')}
                        </Dropdown.Toggle>

                        <Dropdown.Menu as={CustomMenu}>
                        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1"><a className="nav-link" href="/privatecharter">{t('private_charter')}</a></Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2"><a className="nav-link" href="/fulldayfishing">{t('full_day_fishing')}</a></Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1"><a className="nav-link" href="/halfdayfishing">{t('half_day_fishing')}</a></Dropdown.Item>
                        </Dropdown.Menu>
                        </Dropdown>
                    <div><a className="nav-link" href="/help"><BiHelpCircle /> {t('help')}</a></div>
                    <div><a className="nav-link" href="/contact"><FiMail /> {t('contact')}</a></div>
                    <div><FiShoppingCart /> {t('cart')}</div>
                    <div><a className="nav-link" href="/login"><HiOutlineUserGroup /> {t('log_in')}</a></div>
                    <button  onClick={handleShow}>{t('sign_up')}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**UPPDATE:**

3 of the links is not working, the fishing trips, the other ones works like a charm but it doesent reload to the pages i have created.

it just reloads the HomePage.jsx

I have update to the newer code.

**UPPDATE**
when i press the F12 and tab source i can se that the page index and help is generate the same page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a Router Defined with the routes first for Example like this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is taken from the tutorial you referred. In The Code above, you can use it on `App.js`.
For example, you have a Page `FullDayFishing.jsx`. And you want it to be mapped `/full_day_fishing`.
To do that you import it and use the following line of code :
`<Route path="full_day_fishing" element={<FullDayFishing />} />`
This is how you define a route.
Now you can use Link to link it anywhere on the Application.

Comment: I dont come to the new pages i have created when i press on a link, it only runs the homepage.

Comment: Wrap the buttons or the elements that you want to link to specific pages in the `Link` element. When the user clicks that element it will take them to that page. See the examples [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link).